# Python 2.7 : matching expression using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, grouping

I have below strings :

```
asc_epsWarn_mu8                  # I want asc and epsWarn 
asc_ger_phiK_mi16                # I want asc and ger_Phik
ARSrt_FAC_RED5_DSR_AU16            # I want ARSrt and FAC_RED5_DSR
```

Basically I want the the characters before the first `_` in one group and all characters between the first and last underscore `_` in second group.

I am new to regex. Is it possible to write a single regex expression for all above mentioned strings. The Best I could come up with is

```
(\w+)_(\w+)_(\w+)
```

But it does not work. What could be the right regex?

Comment: sorry . I will change it

Comment: This regex will do `([^_]*)_(.*)_[^_\n]*$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LbIqqA/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 capture groups:

```
^([^_]+)_(.+)_[^_]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qkRhQS/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `([^_]+)`: Capture group #1 to match 1+ non-underscore characters
- `_`: Match a `-`
- `(.+)`: Capture group #2 to match 1+ of any character till next match
- `_`: Match a `-`
- `[^_]*`: Match 0 or more non-underscore characters
- `$`: End

Comment: Please explain this regex

Comment: I have added detailed explanation in answer.

Comment: This answer is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The wordcharacter `\w` Also matches an underscore.

If you want to match word characters without the underscore you can  use a negated character class and match a non-whitespace char withtout the underscore `[^\W_]`

You might use 2 capturing groups with a repeating pattern for the second group:

```
^([^\W_]+)_((?:[^\W_]+_)*)[^\W_]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\W_]+)_` Match 1+ times a word char except an underscore in group 1, match underscore
- `(` Capturing group 2

  - `(?:[^\W_]+_)*` Repeat 0+ times matching word char except an underscore, then an underscore
- `)` Close group 2
- `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ times a word char except an underscore
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f7jFWG/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this pattern:

```
([^_]+)_(.*)_.*
```

Sample script:

```
input = "ARSrt_FAC_RED5_DSR_AU16"
matches = re.match(r'([^_]+)_(.*)_.*', input)
if matchObj:
    print "part1: ", matches.group(1)
    print "part2: ", matches.group(2)

part1:  ARSrt
part2:  FAC_RED5_DSR
```

Here is a brief explanation of the regex pattern:

```
([^_]+) match and capture the term before the first underscore
_       match a literal underscore
(.*)    then greedily match and consume everything up until the last undescore
_       match the last underscore
.*      consume the remainder of the string
```